# SQL ERROR ORA-01847: Day of month must be between 1 and last day of month ERROR

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to convert a DDDYYYY varchar field into a date field. However, when i try to insert the date back into a date field i receive the following error message:

> SQL ERROR ORA-01847: Day of month must be between 1 and last day of month ERROR

Below is an example of DDDYYYY data that I am using:

```
 3562015
```

Below is the code that I wrote to convert this:

```
select to_date(to_char(to_date(lpad('3562015', 7, 0), 'DDDYYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as converted_date 
from dual;
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: `DATE` values have no format - so you you don't need to format a `DATE` value to insert it into a `DATE` column. A single `to_date()` call is completely enough

Comment: I am getting an error though... maybe because the column that Im trying to insert into is a timestamp with timezone. are these data types compatible? I thought they were

Comment: `select` and `insert` both work for me (Oracle 12.2, nls_date_format = DD-MON-RR, nls_date_language = ENGLISH, nls_timestamp_tz_format  = DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR). But as others have mentioned, you get a perfectly good `date` from the innermost `to_date()` expression, so you should stop there instead of converting that date into a string and then converting that string back into a date.

Comment: *maybe because the column that Im trying to insert into is a timestamp with timezone* - please post what isn't working.

Comment: i reset my nls_date_format and everything seems to work fine now.... not sure what happened. my apologies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a little confused.  If you want to convert the value, then you only need:

```
select to_date(lpad('3562015', 7, 0), 'DDDYYYY')
```

(and this works).

I'm not sure what the rest of the code is supposed to be doing.  But going back to a string to get back to a date is not useful.